# Azure copy behaviors : best cases for each

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-synapse-analytics

I found many explanations for the copy behavior in Azure.

-- Flatten hierarchy

-- merge Files

-- Preserve Hierarchy

Fine ... Good it's a good start!

but no one explains when to use each!

for the example below, i'm completely stuck ...

"You use Azure Data Factory to prepare data to be queried by Azure Synapse Analytics serverless SQL pools.
Files are initially ingested into an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account as 10 small JSON files. Each file contains the same data attributes and data from a subsidiary of your company.
You need to move the files to a different folder and transform the data to meet the following requirements:
✑ Provide the fastest possible query times.
✑ Automatically infer the schema from the underlying files.
How should you configure the Data Factory copy activity?"

for this question, i could choose either of them.
why merge ? 10 small files, maybe quicker to process one medium ?
if not ? flatten ? but why ? preserve ?? but why again ?

Thank you for your help !

Badr

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**, The above 3 copy behaviors are used in different scenarios.

- **Flatten hierarchy** is used when you want the files from source root folders and sub folders to be in a same folder level in the target folder. It Flattens the hierarchy from the source structure and sets the same level in the target folder.
- **Preserve hierarchy**, as the name suggests it is used when you want to copy files from source to target with the same hierarchy in target location as the source.
- **Merge files** is used to merges the source files and gives a single file in the target location.

Considering your Scenario, **AFAIK**, **Merge files** is better option for your requirements.

> Each file contains the same data attributes and data

It infers the schema from your small JSON files and gives a single file in target which can be used for fast querying.

You can go through this [Documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#recursive-and-copybehavior-examples) for better understanding about these 3 copy behaviors.